# Rails 3.2.1 javascripts in asset directory not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails-3

Oddly I am unable to fire off javascript that is in *.js files that are not the application.js files in the assets/javascripts directory.  For instance, if I make a new rails 3.2.1 application, and insert the following:

index.html.erb:

```
<%= link_to "click", "javascript:", :onclick => "call_function();" %>
```

and my function into a javascript file "anyscript.js":

```
function call_function () {
  alert("hello2");
}
```

The alert function only seems to work if the javascript is put into the application.js file and not anywhere else.  My application.js file has the require_tree . so it should be loading all the scripts within the directory.  But its not working if the function is in a separate file.

I could put all my javascript in the application file, but this is not ideal obviously.  Anyone run into this problem??

Comment: Did you find out what was wrong? I have exactly the same problem...

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the scripts within the directory are being loaded properly and that your require_tree command is correct.  In development mode, verify that the script in question is loaded.  If it is, it will run when the link is clicked.  Only reason it would not is if it is out of scope or undefined.

Comment: Thanks for the response - how do I verify that the script is loaded? It shows up in the source of the browser, oddly enough, but none of the code seems to work when its in the separate file.

Comment: Showing up in the source should be sufficient.  Try putting an alert statement in the script to see if it fires when read.  Also try calling the function from within the browser's javascript debugger.

Comment: So using firebug, I figured out that my additional scripts are not loading.  I am using the //= require_tree .  to include all my js files, but i guess that's not working.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, you sure the anyscript.js file is included in the JS manifest file, a.k.a application.js?

Comment: The file shouldn't need to be included as long as require_tree is being correctly used.

Comment: I have the //= require_tree . there which loads all of the files in the current directory.  However, the code within the file doesn't seem to work when deploying.

Comment: I must not be using require_tree correctly?  Shouldn't it just be //= require_tree .